# Portable utility to capture audio output and input?

Tags: windows, audio, portable, audio-recording

I currently use Audacity's WASAPI feature to capture the audio being outputted by my PC's sound card. I am now, however, in need of a way to capture both audio output as well as microphone input on the same track. It doesn't look like this is possible in Audacity, and I don't want to open up 2 Audacity windows and record output in one and input in the other and then merge them (it would be hard to make the timing exact and even then, I don't know if that would work).

I like Audacity because it is easy to use and is portable (no admin rights required to install which is essential). Is there any lightweight utility I can use that would be able to capture both output and input simultaneously?

Comment: See if any of these work for you https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?sc=317

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Sadly, it looks like none of those (otherwise great) utilities allow for recording from 2 inputs simultaneously (speaker and microphone). In fact, only Audacity seems like it will allow for recording output as an input, but not output and input at the same time

Comment: IMHO, Audacity can do multi-channel recording, but most hardware does not support that. https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/multi_channel_recording.html